# script to distinguish between service accounts and user accounts in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, user-accounts

I need to write a small Linux script to distinguish between a `service` account and a `normal user` account besides printing other details of the users.

Everything works well for me, except for the fact that I doubt if my way of finding whether its an user or service account is full proof.

This is what I'm doing so far with a simple check in my script:

```
awk -F":" '{OFS=":";print $2,$6,$NF}' /etc/passwd | sort | uniq > passwd_processed
reg=".*/[nologin|false]"
while IFS=":" read -r user dir lshell;do
  if [[ "$lshell" =~ $reg ]]; then
     utype="Service"
  else
     utype="User"
  fi
  ....
 ...
 done < passwd_processed
 ...
```

So basically checking the login shell. If it contains `nologin` or `false` (considering service accounts don't have actual shells to login and hence the shells are either `/[usr]/bin/false` or `/[usr]/bin/nologin`), in the shell field, declare them as `Service` accounts else `User` accounts.

Is this check enough. Or is there some further definitive way to know and use in the script to distinguish between `Service` and `User` accounts in Linux ?

Comment: Most operating systems reserve one or more ranges for special purposes, with "regular" user accounts always being larger than some minimal value. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier#Conventions for some examples.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no specific flag to identify a service account.  Your method is valid, as long as you never allow someone to login directly with that user.  At my place, we put something in the comments and put /bin/false as a shell.

Answer (score 0):

As @chepner mentionned, some OS reserve ranges for system or regular users/groups.

If your are on a Debian based distribution, you might want to have a look at `/etc/adduser.conf`:

```
# FIRST_SYSTEM_[GU]ID to LAST_SYSTEM_[GU]ID inclusive is the range for UIDs
# for dynamically allocated administrative and system accounts/groups.
# Please note that system software, such as the users allocated by thebase-passwd
# package, may assume that UIDs less than 100 are unallocated.
FIRST_SYSTEM_UID=100
LAST_SYSTEM_UID=999

FIRST_SYSTEM_GID=100
LAST_SYSTEM_GID=999

# FIRST_[GU]ID to LAST_[GU]ID inclusive is the range of UIDs of dynamically
# allocated user accounts/groups.
FIRST_UID=1000
LAST_UID=59999

FIRST_GID=1000
LAST_GID=59999
```